# err variable space is undefined why?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I run next code and I miss somthing, for me it seem OK :

```
window.onload = TitleFieldInit;
function TitleFieldInit() {
    var str = document.cookie.split("=")[1];
    var space = str.split("=")[1];
    space = space.split(";")[0];
    alert(space);
    // while( space.indexOf('%20' )+1) space = space.replace(/%20/,' ');
    if (document.cookie != "") {
        document.getElementById("TitleField").innerHTML = "Your Title is : " + space;
    }
}​
```

and I got err in FireFox rror"space is undefined" why ?
In chrome "Uncaught TypeError:Cannot call method'split' of Undefined"
Thx for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will never work for any input.

`str` is a already part of result of split by `=`, i.e. it contains no `=` symbols.

Then you split that result again by `=`, which of course will return you one-element array and `str.split("=")[1]` will always be `undefined`.

Looks like you're trying to read cookie value... but second `.split("=")` is not needed at all.

Ah, and you got different results in different browsers, cause they contain different data in their cookies.

PS: Instead of `while( space.indexOf('%20' )+1) space = space.replace(/%20/,' ');` you may write `space = space.replace(/%20/g,' ');` to replace all of them at once.